# Creating an integral for finding the volume of this revolution

Tags: calculus, volume

I need to find the volume of a solid that is created by rotating the area within the following boundaries:

$y=x^3$
$y=8$
$x=0$
which is rotated over $x = 3$.

I thought I had the correct integral with 
$$
\int_{0}^{3} (x-3)(8-x^3)dx
$$

but I do not believe that this is correct. How would I correctly get the integral to solve this?

Comment: It looks as if you are using the Method of Cylindrical Shells. Then it should be $\int_0^2 2\pi(3-x)(8-x^3)\,dx$. One can alternately use slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you draw a picture? You really should for volumes of revolution problems. I will give a few steps here. But your integral is not right.

Graph the region (bounded by green - $x=3$, red - $y=x^3$, and blue - $y=8$ below), then reflect the region across the axis of revolution, the black graph:

[image]

Then you will have a cylinder for which you need to find the volume:

$\pi r^2h$

You're going to do an infinite sum of the volumes, so the integral arrives $\int_{a}^b \pi r^2h$.

Now you just need to figure out r (hint: green minus red), h (hint: which way are you stacking and then shrinking the cylinders? that's your "$dx$ or $dy$"), and limits of integration (figure out h first!)

-- The integral you wrote is not correct. Why? Compare it to what I'm saying should be your base approach: $\int_{a}^b \pi r^2h$.

-- I'm also unsure why you were voted down, as this is a reasonable question that you've clearly attempted.